# Can someone help me with this "Argument `where` of type UserWhereUniqueInput needs at least one of `id` arguments." error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, server, prisma

i put this console log here to see whats receiving:
{
username: 'aa',
gender: 'Feminino',
cargo: '2',
email: 'a',
password: 'a'
}
this is the error message Ive been encountering:

```
Prisma client error: {
  timestamp: 2023-07-22T15:07:56.078Z,
  message: '\n' +
    'Invalid `prisma.user.findUnique()` invocation in\n' +
    'C:\\Users\\luiza\\Documents\\autenticação\\server.js:19:46\n' +
    '\n' +
    '  16   password,\n' +
    '  17 });\n' +
    '  18 try {\n' +
    '→ 19   const existingUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({\n' +
    '         where: {\n' +
    '           email: "a",\n' +
    '       ?   id?: Int,\n' +
    '       ?   AND?: UserWhereInput | UserWhereInput[],\n' +
    '       ?   OR?: UserWhereInput[],\n' +
    '       ?   NOT?: UserWhereInput | UserWhereInput[],\n' +
    '       ?   gender?: StringFilter | String,\n' +
    '       ?   password?: StringFilter | String,\n' +
    '       ?   username?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,\n' +
    '       ?   admin?: BoolFilter | Boolean,\n' +
    '       ?   created_at?: DateTimeFilter | DateTime,\n' +
    '       ?   cargoId?: IntNullableFilter | Int | Null,\n' +
    '       ?   refreshTokens?: RefreshTokenListRelationFilter,\n' +
    '       ?   cargo?: CargoNullableRelationFilter | CargoWhereInput | Null,\n' +
    '       ?   posts?: PostListRelationFilter,\n' +
    '       ?   comments?: CommentListRelationFilter\n' +
    '         }\n' +
    '       })\n' +
    '\n' +
    'Argument `where` of type UserWhereUniqueInput needs at least one of `id` arguments. Available options are listed in green.',
  target: 'user.findUnique'
}
Erro: PrismaClientValidationError:
Invalid `prisma.user.findUnique()` invocation in
  16   password,
  17 });
  18 try {
→ 19   const existingUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
         where: {
           email: "a",
       ?   id?: Int,
       ?   AND?: UserWhereInput | UserWhereInput[],
       ?   OR?: UserWhereInput[],
       ?   NOT?: UserWhereInput | UserWhereInput[],
       ?   gender?: StringFilter | String,
       ?   password?: StringFilter | String,
       ?   username?: StringNullableFilter | String | Null,
       ?   admin?: BoolFilter | Boolean,
       ?   created_at?: DateTimeFilter | DateTime,
       ?   cargoId?: IntNullableFilter | Int | Null,
       ?   refreshTokens?: RefreshTokenListRelationFilter,
       ?   cargo?: CargoNullableRelationFilter | CargoWhereInput | Null,
       ?   posts?: PostListRelationFilter,
       ?   comments?: CommentListRelationFilter
         }
       })
```

client side:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const createAccountBtn = document.getElementById('createAccountBtn');
  const loginBtn = document.getElementById('loginBtn');
  const cargoInput = document.getElementById('cargoInput');
  const nucleoSelection = document.getElementById('nucleoSelection');

  if (createAccountBtn) {
    createAccountBtn.addEventListener('click', handleCreateAccount);
  }

  if (loginBtn) {
    loginBtn.addEventListener('click', handleLogin);
  }

  cargoInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
    const selectedCargo = cargoInput.value;
    // Check if "Líder de Núcleo" or "Membro" is selected, and show or hide the additional selection box accordingly
    if (selectedCargo === 'lider de nucleo' || selectedCargo === 'membro') {
      nucleoSelection.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      nucleoSelection.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
});

async function handleCreateAccount(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const nameInput = document.getElementById('nameInput').value;
  const genderInput = document.getElementById('genderInput').value;
  const cargoInput = document.getElementById('cargoInput').value;
  const nucleoInput = document.getElementById('nucleoInput').value; // Get the selected nucleo value if applicable
  const emailInput = document.getElementById('emailInput').value;
  const passwordInput = document.getElementById('passwordInput').value;
  const genderValue = document.getElementById('genderValue');
  genderValue.value = genderInput;

  try {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/register', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: nameInput,
        gender: genderInput,
        cargo: cargoInput,
        nucleo: nucleoInput, // Pass the selected nucleo value if applicable
        email: emailInput,
        password: passwordInput,
      }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    if (response.ok) {
      alert(data.message);
      redirectToFeed();
    } else {
      alert(data.error);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erro durante o registro:', error);
    alert('Falha no registro.');
  }
}

async function handleLogin() {
  const emailInput = document.getElementById('emaillogin').value;
  const passwordInput = document.getElementById('senhalogin').value;

  try {
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: emailInput,
        password: passwordInput,
      }),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    if (response.ok) {
      // Store the JWT token received from the server securely (e.g., in local storage)
      localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', data.token);
      alert(data.message);
      setTimeout(() => {
        // Clear the input fields after a second
        document.getElementById('emaillogin').value = '';
        document.getElementById('senhalogin').value = '';
      }, 1000);
      redirectToFeed();
    } else {
      alert(data.error);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erro durante o login:', error);
    alert('Falha no login.');
  }
}

function redirectToFeed() {
  window.location.href = '/feedlogado.html';
}
```

server side:

```
const express = require('express');
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const prisma = new PrismaClient();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const jwtSecret = 'yourSecretKey';
const user = await db.collection('users').where('id', userId).get();
function generateToken(user) {
  return jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, jwtSecret, { expiresIn: '8h' }); // Token expires in 8 hours
}

app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: { email: email },
      select: { id: true, email: true, password: true },
    });

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Credenciais inválidas' });
    }
    const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (passwordMatch) {
      const token = generateToken(user);
      return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Login realizado com sucesso!', token, id: user.id, email: user.email });
    } else {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Credenciais inválidas' });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erro durante o login:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Login falhou' });
  }
});

app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  const { username, gender, cargo, nucleo, email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const existingUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: { email },
    });

    if (existingUser) {
      return res.status(409).json({ error: 'Email already exists' });
    }
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

    const existingCargo = await prisma.cargo.findUnique({ where: { name: cargo } });

    if (!existingCargo) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Cargo not found' });
    }

    let nucleoConnect;
    if (nucleo && !isNaN(parseInt(nucleo))) {
      const existingNucleo = await prisma.nucleo.findUnique({ where: { id: parseInt(nucleo) } });
      if (!existingNucleo) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Nucleo not found' });
      }
      nucleoConnect = { connect: { id: existingNucleo.id } };
    }

    const newUser = await prisma.user.create({
      data: {
        username,
        gender,
        cargo: {
          connect: { id: existingCargo.id },
        },
        nucleo: nucleoConnect,
        email,
        password: hashedPassword,
      },
    });

    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Conta criada com sucesso!' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erro:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Registro falhou.' });
  }
});


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Servidor iniciado em http://localhost:${port}`);
});

process.on('SIGINT', () => {
  console.log('Received SIGINT. Closing server...');
  server.close(() => {
    console.log('Server closed.');
    prisma.$disconnect().then(() => {
      console.log('Prisma client disconnected.');
      process.exit(0);
    });
  });
});

prisma.$on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('Prisma client error:', err);
});
```

also, if it helps, this is my prisma model:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "sqlite"
  url      = "file:./database.db"
}

model User {
  id         Int   @id @default(autoincrement())
  gender     String   
  password   String   
  username   String?   
  email      String @unique
  refreshTokens RefreshToken[]
  admin      Boolean  @default(false)
  created_at DateTime @default(now())
  
  cargo      Cargo?   @relation(fields: [cargoId], references: [id])
  cargoId    Int?

  posts      Post[]
  comments   Comment[]
}

model Cargo {
  id         Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  nome       String   
  nucleo     String   
  created_at DateTime @default(now())

  users      User[]
}

model Post {
  id                            Int @id @default(autoincrement())
  content                       String
  updated_at                    DateTime @updatedAt
  created_at                    DateTime @default(now())

  comment Comment[]

  userId Int
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
}

model Comment {

  id Int @id @default(autoincrement()) 
  content String

  postId Int
  post Post @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])

  userId Int
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  
} 
model RefreshToken {
  id          Int   @id @default(autoincrement())
  hashedToken String
  userId      Int      
  User        User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  revoked     Boolean  @default(false)
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

Ive already tried checking if its collecting it right and all but I cant find whats wrong (still learning)

Answer (score 8):

```
'Argument `where` of type UserWhereUniqueInput needs at least one of `id` arguments. Available options are listed in green.'
```

From your stacktrace, what I gather is that Prisma does not know that the email field is unique. Your query looks fine. So I think your problem is that you need to regenerate your prisma client.

In my experience working with Prisma, sometimes after pushing schema changes to the DB, the client is not automatically regenerated.

Try: `prisma generate` in your terminal.

Comment: It's important to run the `prisma generate` after any change  made to the **db schema**